# Why does Islam forbid premarital sex if both are devoted and seek to get married in future?

Tags: nikah, zina

If men and women are in a boyfriend-girlfriend relationship and are committed to each other and are seeking to get married down the lane, then why does Islam forbid such a relationship? What is the harm in such a relationship?

If both are devoted and are seeking marriage why not be able to have sex?

I'd like the translated excerpts from the holy book that specifically states that such a relationship is haram and that any contact including intercourse while in such a relationship is haram as well.

Comment: honestly i feel you are just looking for an excuse.

Comment: Do you know the future?

Answer (score 3):

**if you are so committed and are planning to get married in future , then whats the harm in marrying now?**

if your answer to this question is : we are studying or we want to get devoted to our career we are not financially stable.

then my question will be what if (god forbade) in future you were unable to meet your goal, then will you not marry that person?

if your answer to this question is Yes we will still marry
then i think you can marry now also.

if your answer is NO, then have you ever thought about the future of your child(if any) due to your relationship which is not legal. and what about the emotional harm that you cause to the other person.

Comment: Is that your opinion or "Islam's" opinion? I mean where in the quran or haditz is this actually explained? Why not married? Many reasons. Say you don't like rules made by your government governing marriage.

Comment: @SharenEayrs in islam premarital sex is haram. this is not my personal opinion.

Comment: And you didn't mention that in your answer. Instead you mumble about something else. I am not asking if that something else is right or wrong. Is it islam? Or is it your opinion?

Comment: @SharenEayrs what do you mean? what reasons? what rules?